# Does it matter if I use RunWithElevatedPrivileges in SPJobDefinition?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have written a custom `SPJobDefinition`. In the `public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)` method I am running some code which is encapsulated in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. Since the jobs are executed under the app pool account (this is a true statement, right?), what is the benefit/purpose of running it under System Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From msdn about SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

> Executes the specified method with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control

Jobs are executed under SharePoint timer service account. This account could have not full control permissions. It's permissions could be restricted.

Answer (score -1):

Pls refer to these discussion...I hope you will get the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036589/problem-in-creating-timer-job
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/696a640f-4b8d-44ce-a970-e05bd45c437f/timer-job-and-runwithelevatedpriviliges
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340771/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-sharepoint-timer-jobs

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.